# Necessity for a muslim to learn how to swim

Tags: halal-haram, hadith

I am trying to find any hadiths that can support (and encourage) the argument for muslim men and women to learn to swim.

I have found the following hadiths:

> - "Teach your children swimming, archery and horse riding"
> - "All things in which there is no remembrance of Allah are frivolity    and idle play except for four things, and he mentioned teaching another to swim"
>
> (At-Tabarani, exact reference unknown, i.e page, book, and hadith number)

I would appreciate it if someone could give an exact reference, including original Arabic, and as well as where the source is listed.

**Edit**

*Another source:*

> “Every activity that does not contain the remembrance of Allaah is
>   falsehood and heedlessness, except for a man doing four things:
>   Walking between two purposeful goals, grooming his horse, playing with
>   his family, or teaching someone to swim.”

According the following [website](https://researchcenterforhadith.wordpress.com/category/hadith/page/24/):

> An authentic hadeeth, with varying but similar wordings, collected by
>   Ahmad (4/144,146,148,222), Aboo Daawood (3/13), Ibn Maajah (2/940),
>   Ad-Daarimee (2/204-205), Al-Haakim (2/95), Al-Bayhaqee (10/13,14,218),
>   and many others

Again, I would appreciate if someone could guide me towards confirming these sources.

Answer (score 1):

From Rasulullah *peace be upon him*:

3877 - Teach your children swimming and archery and women spindle. too much [Da'eef](http://www.alahazrat.net/islam/what-is-daeef-hadith-how-it-becomes-hasan.php)

> 3877 - (علموا أبناءكم السباحة والرمي، والمرأة المغزل) . ضعيف جداً

The source of above mention quotation but still need more investigation. http://www.ahlalhdeeth.com/vb/showpost.php?s=67140a4d6594d2be5c8c14b37cb4f253&p=1814852&postcount=7

[Al-Albani corrected the following Hadith](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/21898)

> “Every activity that does not contain the remembrance of Allaah is
> falsehood and heedlessness, except for a man doing four things:
> Walking between two purposeful goals, grooming his horse, playing with
> his family, or teaching someone to swim.”

From Omar ibn AL Khattab:

"Teach your children swimming, archery and horse riding"- Authentic

> نص الحديث ( علموا آبناءكم السباحة ، والرمي ، وركوب الخيل ) حكم الحديث
> [ صح عن عمر رضي الله عنه]

Answer (score 0):

Although there are is a Hadith that mentions swimming, archery and horse riding as already posted elsewhere on the page but it is not to be found in any of the major compilations(see below) as far as I can tell. In fact archery is mentioned several times.(https://sunnah.com/search/?q=archery+) Hence, it would be better to encourage people to learn swimming by appealing to common sense and real benefits that are timeless as opposed to giving it a religious wrapping.

Sahih al-Bukhari

Sahih Muslim

Sunan an-Nasa'i

Sunan Abi Dawud

Jami` at-Tirmidhi

Sunan Ibn Majah

Muwatta Malik

Comment: Some parents use religion as an excuse to prevent their children from learning swimming, hence why I asked for Islamic sources that confirm the importance of learning children how to swim.

Comment: While I appreciate your efforts but we cannot invent new sources or shore up less than authentic sources. It is always better to educate the doubters with reason and logic and at the same time point out the benefits. After all that is exactly what Islam teaches.